# How can I trick websites into displaying their iPad versions on chrome running on windows?

Tags: google-chrome, website, ipad

I have a Windows touchscreen netbook and would like to see websites as they appear to a iPad user (i know many sites have special versions for the iPad). I'm using Chrome.

None of the solutions found searching on Google seem to work...

Comment: Changing user-agent would be the first way I'd try. However, keep in mind that this is completely site dependent. It all depends on how the developers implement their browser detection algorithm.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This might be useful if you've not tried it already: [iPad Peek](http://mashable.com/2010/04/05/ipad-peek/).

For more information: whether a site will show an iPad version of the site is likely to depend on the HTTP request sent by the browser; it contains what browser has sent the request and the site would decide to send the iPad version back (search for "HTTP request" and "User-Agent" if you're interested in any further reading).

You could build a HTTP request that uses [the iPad User-Agent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2153877/what-is-the-ipad-user-agent):

`Mozilla/5.0(iPad; U; CPU iPhone OS 3_2 like Mac OS X; en-us) AppleWebKit/531.21.10 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0.4 Mobile/7B314 Safari/531.21.10`

using: [Fiddler](http://www.fiddlertool.com/fiddler2/version.asp) and see the response.

---

**EDIT:** Here's information on [changing your user-agent in Chrome](http://www.labnol.org/software/change-google-chrome-user-agent-string/4566/). That is a bit simpler than building your HTTP requests.